# Playing sound automatically when transitioning to a slide in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, slideshow, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How do I make a sound play when I transition to a certain slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how **(*)**
[Add a Sound Effect to the Slide Transition](http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/powerpoint2007/ss/07transitions_3.htm)

But I think I speek on the behalf of everyone when I say **Please don't do it!**

---

*****(Note, this points to side 3of3 click on *prev* to get the full tutorial )